# How to install an eclipse plugin in eclipse luna j2ee platform?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have made an eclipse plugin which is built using maven tycho. When I put the resulting jar in dropins folder of eclipse installation folder and restart eclipse, I am able to see the plugin in the 'New' wizard. But doing the same in eclipse luna EE IDE, the plugin is not visible. 
Is there any other way of installing such plugin on eclipse java EE IDE luna platform?

Comment: All Eclipse packages behave the same way as far as installing plugins is concerned. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message about the install.

Comment: I checked the logs, but there is nothing about that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There was a difference in versions of some jars are in eclipse java EE platform and in the plugin that I built. I changed the versions and and re-built the plugin jar. Now its working perfectly.